# The supersolvability of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

$G$ is a finite solvable group and $G=PR$, where $P\in $ Syl$_{p}(G)$, $R\in $ Syl$_{2}(G)$ and $|R|=2$.

By Burnside's Theorem, we have that $P$ is normal in $G$. Can we get that $G$ is supersolvable?

Comment: Yes, a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $P$ is central in $P$ and is an irreducible module under the action of $R$, so it must be cyclic.

Comment: Whether we need to show that every chief factor of $G$ below $P$ is cyclic in order to get that $G$ is supersolvable?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. A finite group is supersolvable if and only if its chief factors are all cyclic. The proof in my first comment is elementary.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the proof in your first comment.

Comment: @MoomooAngelline Consider the action of an involution generating $R$ on $P$, using Derek Holt's argument to take off chief factors inductively.